# Javascript, removing value from modal on close

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap, this is my link from an image, using data-* attribute (first time). The link works, loading an image in the modal.

```
<a href="#" class="portfolio-box" data-img-url="01" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-fullscreen">
    <img src="daco-portfolio-01.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
</a>
```

I'm trying to remove the previous image from the modal before loading another in.
I can achieve this by hard coding the value $('#portfolio-item-01).hide()
but would like this to remove the item, dynamically.

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="port-wrap" id="portfolio-item-01" style="display: block;">
        <img src="img/portfolio/daco-portfolio-01.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

I think I understand there is a scope issue on the value "item_num" but I just can't see the result. 
Thanks.

```
$(function() {
    $('.portfolio-box').on('click', function() {
        var item_num = $(this).attr('data-img-url');
        $('#portfolio-item-' + item_num).fadeIn();
        console.log("end Item num : " + item_num);
        return item_num;
    });
});

//close button inside modal
$(function() {
    $('.btn').on('click', function() {
        console.log('clicked');
        $('#portfolio-item-' + item_num).hide(); //trying to pass item_num
        console.log(item_num);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

When ever a modal is closed, an event is fired "hidden.bs.modal".
You can listen for this event and call the appropriate function when the event is fired.

```
$("#modal-id").on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
//your code...
        })
```

Comment: Thanks rramakrishnaa

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work.

```
$(function() {
    var currItem;
    $('.portfolio-box').on('click', function() {
        var item_num = $(this).attr('data-img-url');
        $('#portfolio-item-' + item_num).fadeIn();
        console.log("end Item num : " + item_num);
        currItem = item_num;
        //return item_num;
    });
    $('.btn').on('click', function() {
        console.log('clicked');
        $('#portfolio-item-' + currItem).hide(); //Current item variable 
        console.log(currItem);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, funny I almost had this above, but left it out side the main function call.